# C code generating a "zsh segmentation fault"

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, primes

I wrote a simple script to calculate prime numbers but when I compile and run it, I get this error and always after 106747.

```
...
106727
106739
106747
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out 1000000
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int *Primes;

int isPrime(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    int calc_to = ceil(sqrt(n));
    while (Primes[i] < calc_to) {
        if (n % Primes[i] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        i ++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
            printf("Usage: ./a.out <Find Till>");
            return 0;
    }

    int Len = 3;
    Primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * Len);
    Primes[0] = 2; Primes[1] = 3;
    printf("2\n3\n");

    int calc_to = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int n = 4; n < calc_to; n++) {
        if (isPrime(n) == 1) {
                Primes[Len - 1] = n;
                printf("%d\n", n);
                Primes = realloc(Primes, sizeof(int) * Len);
                Len ++;
            }
        }
    free(Primes);
}
```

Does anyone know what my mistake is? I have no clue.

I'm running Mac OS Catalina (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem:  each time you increment the array by one you call realloc . This is very inefficient.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Perhaps read also the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf); see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) before

Comment: You should never assign the return value of `realloc` to the pointer variable that was passed to `realloc`. If the function returns `NULL` you cannot access the initial memory location any longer.

Comment: Why do you increment `Len` **after** using it for `realloc`?

Answer (score 3):

Make `Len` a global variable and change `isPrime` to this:

```
int isPrime(int n) {
  int i = 0;
  int calc_to = ceil(sqrt(n));
  while (Primes[i] < calc_to) {
    if (i >= Len)                 // add this line
    {                             // add this line
      printf("Bummer");           // add this line
      exit(1);                    // add this line
    }                             // add this line
    if (n % Primes[i] == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

You'll notice that at some point `i` is greater equal than `Len`, meaning that you're accessing the `Primes` array out of bounds which leads to undefined behaviour.